# como puedo guardar el valor de un JSpinner en una variable?

Tags: eclipse, java-swing

necesito guardar el valor de un *JSpinner* que a escogido el usuario en una variable para poder utilizarlo o poder mostrarlo.

el *JSpinner* recorre de `1 a 10` y si el usuario escoge el numero `5` quiero guardar ese numero para poder utilizarlo

Answer (score 0):

Tan facil como:

```
Integer valor = (Integer)miJSpinner.getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como podrías utilizarlo..

```
public class SpinnerTest {
    JTextField campoTexto;
    JSpinner spinner;
    JFrame marco;

    SpinnerTest(){
        campoTexto = new JTextField(20); 
        //Creamos modelo para JSpinner y lo inicializamos
        SpinnerModel modeloSpinner = new SpinnerNumberModel(3, 0, 10, 1);
        spinner = new JSpinner(modeloSpinner);
        //capturamos cambios del JSpinner
        spinner.addChangeListener(e -> {
            campoTexto.setText(spinner.getValue().toString());
            //Guardamos valor del spinner escogido por el usuario
            int valorSpinner = Integer.parseInt(spinner.getValue().toString());
            if(valorSpinner == 5)
                System.out.println("Este es el valor 5");
        });

        //Creacion Marco con los componentes
        marco = new JFrame("JSpinner");
        marco.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        marco.add(spinner);
        marco.add(campoTexto);
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        marco.setVisible(true);
        marco.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpinnerTest();
    }
}
```